# I get an error when execution the function clustal() in r

Tags: r, clustal

I am beginner R and I try to run the command `clustal(sylvia.seq)`

I get the following error:

```
sh: clustalw2: command not found
Error in clustal(sylvia.seq) : 
   cannot find executable ‘clustalw2’ on your computer.
  It is recommended that you place the executable of Clustal
  in a directory on the PATH of your computer which is:
/bin
/Library/TeX/texbin
/opt/X11/bin
/sbin
/usr/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
In addition: Warning message:
In system(paste(exec, opts), ignore.stdout = quiet) :
  error in running command
```

I saw in another post how to fix it for windows, but unfortunately I am using macos, and I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have permissions to add the file in any folder, but **/opt/X11/bin**.

So I added there and now it works, but I tried with the rest and wasn't able to do so.